# How is it concluded from Yerushalmi Shevi'it 6:1 that Rabbi Yishmael b'Rabbi Yosei was a kohen?

Tags: kohen-priest, tannaim, talmud-yerushalmi, teruma, maseches-sheviis

I heard a number of months ago that it can be concluded from [Yerushalmi Shevi'it 6:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Jerusalem_Talmud_Sheviit.6.1.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that Rabbi Yishmael b'Rabbi Yosei was a kohen (this topic in itself is debated, see a short summary in his [Hebrew Wikipedia entry](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99_%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%90%D7%9C_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%99)). This seems to be the relevant portion:

> "דְּבֵי רִבִּי יִשְׁמָעֵאל בֵּי רִבִּי יוֹסֵי וּבֶן הַקַּפָּר נִמְנוּ עַל אֲוֵיר אַשְׁקְלוֹן וְטִיהֲרוּהוּ. מִפִּי רִבִּי פִּינְחָס בֶּן יָאִיר שֶׁאָמַר יוֹרְדִּין הָייִנוּ לְסִירְקִי שֶׁל אַשְׁקְלוֹן וְלוֹקְחִין חִטִּין וְעוֹלִין לְעִירֵנוּ וְטוֹבְלִין וְאוֹכְלִין בִּתְרוּמָתֵינוּ. לְמָחָר נִמְנוּ עָלֶיהָ לְפוֹטְרָהּ מִן הַמַּעְשְׂרוֹת. מָשַׁךְ רִבִּי יִשְׁמָעֵאל בֵּי רִבִּי יוֹסֵי אֶת יָדָיו שֶׁהָיָה מִסְתַּמֵּךְ עַל בֶּן הַקַּפָּר. אָמַר לוֹ בְּנִי לָמָּה לֹא אָמַרְתָּ לִי מִפְּנֵי מַה מָשַׁכְתָּ אֶת יָדֶיךָ מִמֶּנִּי הָייִתִי אוֹמֵר לָךְ אֶתְמוֹל אֲנִי הוּא שֶׁטִּימֵּאתִי אֲנִי הוּא שֶׁטִּיהַרְתִּי וְעַכְשָׁיו אֲנִי אוֹמֵר שֶׁמָּא נִתְכַּבְּשָׁה מִדְּבַר תּוֹרָה. וְהֵיאַךְ אֲנִי פוֹטְרָהּ מִדְּבַר תּוֹרָה."

I can see that Rabbi Pinchas ben Yair is quoted stating that he and others used to go to Ashkelon to eat trumot, so that would point to him being a kohen. But how is this also understood about Rabbi Yishmael b'Rabbi Yosei? Or is that just a mistaken understanding of the gemara?

Comment: Hi @Harel13 - are you asking in general from where do we know that he is a kohen or davka from that passage. Meaning to say, there are other places where we see him engaged in acts of kehunah...

Comment: @Dov in this question I'm asking particularly about this passage, but I'd be happy to hear of other sources. I'm only familiar with the one brought in the wiki entry of his almost receiving of ראשית הגז.

Comment: Take a look at this - https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnat_Eretz_Yisrael_on_Mishnah_Ketubot.2.8.11?vhe=Mishnat_Eretz_Yisrael,_Seder_Nashim,_Jerusalem,_2013-2019&lang=bi&lookup=%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%20%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99%20%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%90%D7%9C%20%D7%91%D7%99%20%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99%20%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%99.%20%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%99%20%D7%9C%D7%90%20%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%93%D7%AA%D7%99%20%D7%A2%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA&with=Lexicon&lang2=en

Comment: Can only a kohen testify that another person is a kohen?